# AreaContentRenderer Ctor does not take IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I need to overrid the ContentAreaRenderer to implement DisplayOptions on all templates.

I need the display option to render in the ContentArea so that it will affect all templates.

Ive tried to implement this solution 
https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Anders-Hattestad/Dates/2014/8/Extending-ContentArea-to-use-custom-CSS-class-on-child-elements/

What goes wrong
I get the error 
"ContentFragmentAttributeAssembler is obsolete use IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler instead"
When i change the type i get a problem because of the base constructor does not take en IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler but rather the obsolete ContentFragmentAttributeAssembler

```
   public class ContentAreaRendererWithDisplayOptionWithCss : ContentAreaRenderer
    {
        private readonly DisplayOptions _displayOptionsOwn;
        private readonly IContentRepository _contentRepositoryOwn;
        public ContentAreaRendererWithDisplayOptionWithCss()
            : this(
                  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRenderer>(), 
                  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TemplateResolver>(), 
                  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler>(), 
                  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>(), 
                  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DisplayOptions>())
        {

        }
        public ContentAreaRendererWithDisplayOptionWithCss(
            IContentRenderer contentRenderer, 
            TemplateResolver templateResolver, 
            IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler attributeAssembler, 
            IContentRepository contentRepository, 
            DisplayOptions displayOptions)
            : base(contentRenderer, 
                  templateResolver, 
                  attributeAssembler, 
                  contentRepository, 
                  displayOptions)
        {
            _displayOptionsOwn = displayOptions;
            _contentRepositoryOwn = contentRepository;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to rearrange your attributes. It looks to me like the new constructor does take an IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler:

[image]

In your example, you're not passing an IContentAreaLoader, which should be the last argument in the base constructor, instead of your display DisplayOptions.

```
public ContentAreaRendererWithDisplayOptionWithCss(
        IContentRenderer contentRenderer,
        TemplateResolver templateResolver,
        IContentAreaItemAttributeAssembler attributeAssembler,
        IContentRepository contentRepository,
        IContentAreaLoader contentAreaLoader,
        DisplayOptions displayOptions)
        : base(contentRenderer, 
              templateResolver, 
              attributeAssembler, 
              contentRepository,
              contentAreaLoader)
    {
        _displayOptionsOwn = displayOptions;
        _contentRepositoryOwn = contentRepository;
    }
```